# Best design pattern for selecting a group with in a list with the value of the condition may vary?

Tags: java, design-patterns

```
public class Swimmers extends SwimmersPrototype{
    List<Swimmer> swimmers;
    SortStrategy sortStrategy;

    public Swimmers() {
        swimmers = new ArrayList();
    }

    @Override
    public SwimmersPrototype clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
        Swimmers swp = (Swimmers)super.clone();
        return swp;
    }

    public void setSortStrategyAndSort(SortStrategy s) {
        setSortStrategy(s);
        sort();
    }

    public void setSortStrategy(SortStrategy s){
        sortStrategy = s;
    }

    public void addSwimmer(Swimmer s){
        swimmers.add(s);
    }

    public List<Swimmer> sort() {
        return (swimmers = sortStrategy.sort(new ArrayList<>(swimmers)));
    }

    public List<Swimmer> getSwimmers() {
        return swimmers;
    }
}
```

I've Swimmers class to act as an in-memory database of Swimmer records. I've three tables one to show list of swimmer, second one to list swimmers with only age between 18-25, and the last one to list swimmers with only age 26-35.

Swimmer class have an age property, but the age of a Swimmer may change and may result in another age group, like if John is 25 and celebrate his birthday while in the game, he must be in the second group.

So here which design pattern is best to select a group based on some condition in a list, also the value of the condition may vary so it results change in a group?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get if you are asking for an algorithm to search in your list or a design patter to achieve something else like changing your strategy at runtime

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want the design pattern which can simply select a group in a list with some condition that the strategy may change at runtime.

Comment: What's wrong with your current implementation? The Strategy Pattern seems to fit your needs as far as I understand.

Comment: Instead of making objects such as `Swimers` and `SortStrategy` why don't you just keep all the swimers in one list. `List<Swimer> swimers =...` and when you want to retrieve a particular group of swimers just use `stream().filter()` to return the result you want. Example: `swimmers.stream().filter(swimmer -> swimmer.getAge() >= 18 && swimmer.getAge() <= 25);` will return all swimers whose age is between 18 and 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `Predicate` for each case you need:

```
Predicate<Integer> youngSwimmer = integer -> integer > 18 && integer < 25;
Predicate<Integer> oldSwimmer = integer -> integer > 26 && integer < 35;
```

Then test it like this:

```
List<Swimmer> = getSwimmers().stream()
    .filter(swimmer -> youngSwimmer.test(swimmer.getAge()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

You can define a separate mehtod for this and pass any predicate you need to get list of Swimmers of specific age